# Error creating hive table : mismatched input 'LOCATION' expecting EOF

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am trying to create new table in hive as follows :

```
CREATE DATABASE FAMILY;

USE FAMILY;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS FAMILY.abc (name STRING COMMENT 'Member Name', Age INT COMMENT 'Age of the Member') 
COMMENT 'basic details of fmaily members'
TBLPROPERTIES ('creator'='Sarang', 'created_at'='2019-10-06 14:00:00') 
LOCATION " /user/hive/warehouse/family/abc";
```

Gives me the error as below.

```
FAILED: Parse Error: line 4:0 mismatched input 'LOCATION' expecting EOF near ')'
```

How do i provide explicit location for my hive table.

Comment: ```LOCATION``` goes before ```TBLPROPERTIES``` src: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/hive/LanguageManual+DDL

Comment: In addition to what @GrzegorzSkibinski said,  why the location contains space at the beginning?